Building a soroban smart contract on stellar but having target/core problems
I am following the starter tutorial from original web site Getting Started on stellar.org but encountering problems at ```` stellar contract build` ``` step.
It returns me the error shown below.
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`

As suggested in the tutorial i have run the
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

command to install target, and confirmed it with
❯ rustup target list --installed

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

showing that target is installed. After seeing another target is also existing, i tought that maybe it confuses the targets so i tried
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release

command which is stated in tutorial performs same action as  stellar contract build  but i hoped that typing the target clears any confusion. Still i recived same error with  stellar contract build  stating that "cant find core".
So i have removed the target with
rustup target remove wasm32-unknown-unknown

the used the  rustup target list --installed  ensure target is actually removed. Seeing that target it not there i run
cargo clean 

which stated that it removed 1 gb of data. Then i have  run
rustup update
cargo update

to ensure everything is up to date
then reinstalled the target with
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

then ensured the installation with
rustup target list --installed

Trying to build again yielded same error about not finding core.
So i tried to  remove target > remove tool chain > install toolchain > intstal target with commands below.
rustup target remove wasm32-unknown-unknown
rustup toolchain uninstall stable
rustup toolchain install stable
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

To get the same error message again.
What should i do to make it see the core?

Turns out my rust installment is corrupted. So i have solved it first removing the rust with command
rustup self uninstall

then installed with
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

then added it to
source "$HOME/.cargo/env.fish"

that is a fish sspecific command given by rust installation. using bash or zsh there is a diffrent command.
after that
rustup update

Now it works as intended.
Rust had no problem previously on my device, so it is definitely an unique case.
